# 'baseColor' was deprecated in visionOS 1.0: use `color` property instead

Tags: swift, realitykit, visionos

I am displaying an image on a plane after loading it from URL in visionOS app.
It works fine, but I am getting this warning:

`baseColor` was deprecated in visionOS 1.0: use `color` property instead

```swift
static func fetch(url: String) {
   let remoteURL = URL(string: url)!
          
   let fileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
           
   let data = try! Data(contentsOf: remoteURL)
   try! data.write(to: fileURL)

   do {
        let texture = try TextureResource.load(contentsOf: fileURL)
        var material = SimpleMaterial()
        material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)
        
   } catch  {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

If I try to fix it by doing this:

```
 material.color = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'MaterialColorParameter' to type 'SimpleMaterial.BaseColor' (aka 'PhysicallyBasedMaterial.BaseColor')
```

Do you know where might be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleMaterial.BaseColor` (iOS 15+) is different type than `SimpleMaterial.MaterialColorParameter` (iOS 13+). You can't assign different types to each other. Try this:

```swift
do {
    let texture = try TextureResource.load(contentsOf: fileURL)
    var material = SimpleMaterial()
    material.color = SimpleMaterial.BaseColor(tint: .white, texture: .init(texture))
}
```